# Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object, How to resolve it?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm working in a web application that work in asp.net with Ajax but I have a problem, I'm having the message error:

Error:

```
Sys.Webforms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

This is Image link http://postimg.org/image/s6tpnjsjt/ Please visit and see error screen shot.

My System was stable for 20 minutes after 20 minutes i clicked on any button but page is not responding and above error raised.

How can i resolve this?
Thanks in advance.